# How to copy data to a specific HPC node without knowing which node it is before the job starts

Tags: jobs, hpc, pbs

due to a peculiar configuration of our HPC, the best way to run our code is to copy the data from a headnode to a hard drive on a specific node to run the analysis on (we're using one node at a time).

Because the PBS assigns the nodes dynamically to jobs, I do not know beforehand which node I am supposed to copy the data to. I would like to extract the information on which node the job will be run and insert it dynamically in my script.

So when my script starts it would first copy the data from the headnode to  one of available nodes and then run the job script on this data on that specific node to which the data had been copied.

Is this doable at all? I thought I could use $PBS_NODEFILE for this, but it only contains the list of nodes available and not the "currently selected" one. I looked through the PBS options and special variables but there is nothing obvious that could be applied in this way.

Just to clarify, I **cannot** *a priori* decide which node to copy to and hard-code it into my jobscript (I know how to do this, but it's not what I want).

Any suggestions welcome :-)
kJ

Comment: Aren't you just looking for a path relative to the current working directory on the node executing the job ?

Comment: Possibly - the trick is to figure out which node will be executing the job.

Comment: If using PBS Professional or Torque you could use the `stagein` job attribute to specify the files that need to be copied to the node ahead of the start of the job.

Comment: Also I could not understand your remark regarding the `$PBS_NODEFILE` content. It lists only the nodes allocated for the job. Could you please post an example of your job script?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the right environmental variable that holds the information about the node - it's $HOSTNAME. So in my script I can declare (among other things)

```
ssh $HOSTNAME
```

and get onto the node.

Or I can copy stuff directly onto/from the node with

```
scp input $HOSTNAME:/local/
scp $HOSTNAME:/local/ output
```

and variations thereof.